# Trying to match a simple phone number C# Regex

Tags: c#, .net

```
Match match = Regex.Match("555-5555555", "^(\\d{3}\\-?\\d{3}\\-?\\d{4})$", RegexOptions.None);
it["Should match"] = () => match.Success.should_be_true();
```

The above should match i believe. I require the numbers, but leaving the hyphens as optional. However, the above returns false and fails the test.

**Edit**

Accepted answer as Darin is right, something is wrong with my test scope. Here's my updated code that passes:

```
Match match;
    void describe_example()
    {

        context["goodregex"] = () =>
        {
            before = () => match = Regex.Match("555-5555555", "^(\\d{3}\\-?\\d{3}\\-?\\d{4})$", RegexOptions.None);
            it["Should match"] = () => match.Success.should_be_true();
        };

        context["badregex"] = () =>
        {
            before = () => match = Regex.Match("555-5525-5555", "^(\\d{3}\\-?\\d{3}\\-?\\d{4})$", RegexOptions.None);
            it["Should not match"] = () => match.Success.should_be_false();
        };

    }
```

Comment: `match.Success` is true on my machine.

Comment: Same here :) It returns true. Btw I recommend using the "as is"( or verbatum) operator when writing a Regex string. This is very confusing: `@"^(\d{3}\-?\d{3}\-?\d{4})$"`

Comment: Is `it["Should match"]` only ever set at the provided line?

Comment: Yes, below it to test that 555-5255-5555 is not valid, I use "Should not match". Only the above failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following program prints true:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var match = Regex.Match("555-5555555", "^(\\d{3}\\-?\\d{3}\\-?\\d{4})$", RegexOptions.None);
        Console.WriteLine(match.Success);
    }
}
```

I guess you are having some scoping issue in your unit test where the `match` variable is being modified when running tests concurrently.

Comment: I think you're right. I was merely testing this is another app i had open since it was an easy way to check the regex for a quick server side validation I wanted to add. I just tried it in a separate app like yours there and it worked fine.

Comment: Accepted your answer, updated my code below original question to show how tests are passing.

Answer (score 1):

Your RegEx works correctly on my machine. For regex that validate different types of telephone numbers please look here (you could compare with your needs and choose the most appropriate one):

http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but please do not post **only** links. Provide also some short explanation of the content or giva code example.

Comment: Well the RegEx is true so you want me to post what ?

Comment: I mean your post. If you make a post, that means that you **answer** the question. If you **answer** the question be more decriptive, not only links. That is.

Comment: Well unfortunatly I was disconnected during the reponse I just updated it.

Comment: I updated the answer to what I really wanted to say. So could you please remove the downvote since I don't think that it is appropriate. You don't have to always post code to give an helpful answer (espacially not in this case).

Comment: De Oliviera: I'm not a downvoter, but +1 for *corrected* answer

Answer (score 0):

The regex looks fine to me. And in fact `match.Success` is true on my machine. I'd probably rewrite the regex as:

```
"^(\\d{3}\\-?){2}\\d{4}$"
```

However, that's only a matter of preference.